# Who is watching the resurrection happen?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

In the MCU series *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*, we learn of the resurrection of S.H.I.E.L.D. agent Phil Coulson through the T.A.H.I.T.I. process. In the background of the scene in which this occurs, there are a few people. The MCU Wikia page says that Nick Fury is supposedly there, but I can't really tell. Is there any source that says who these people are?

[image]

Comment: Why assume there are specific people involved, and not just random scientists?

Answer (score -1):

[Wikia](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Resurrection_of_Phil_Coulson), contrary to your assertion in the OP, lists Doctors [Streiten](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Streiten) and [Goodman](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Goodman) as being involved.

Comment: The Wikia, while a fan-created source by itself, does not mention who is present. Only who *executes* the project. If Nick Fury was an observer, for example, he would be present, but not listed as part of the execution.